# How can i make a slider of product thumbnail images on product page

Tags: product, ce-1.9.0.1

I am searching for a extension to add product thumbnail image slider in the product page but couldn't find any of the free extension so i can anyone help me in making custom product thumbnail slider for my magento store. any help will be appreciable for me.

Comment: try this..  https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-thumbnail-image-slider.html

Answer (score 2):

In my case i did slider for the more images in the product page by adding bxslider through jQuery.Use bxslider.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#recently').bxSlider({
    auto: false,
    pager: false,
    slideWidth: 170,
    slideMargin:28,
    controls: true,
    infiniteLoop:false,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 4,
    moveSlides: 1,
    preloadImages:'all'
  });
});
```

here id recently is the id of the ul.i gave the id to the ul myself

```
<ul class="product-image-thumbs" id="recently">
```

in Media.phtml

Comment: thanks for your help pradeep but currently i am getting one thumbnail image option for product so how can i get the multiple thumbnail image for a single product so that i will make use of bxslider to add slider of product thumbnail images

Comment: in the backend go to Catalog > Manage Products > then go to the product their you see the Images tab in the left.for current image their will be only one image as you said their is one.upload more images and save and on the frontend you will see the more images as thumbnail

Comment: @ Pradeep Sanku, thank you.It works for me. Magento 1.9.1.0 + BxSlider 4.1.2. Preview: http://i.imgur.com/A21yhtm.png

Answer (score 2):

First you need to add any jquery carousel into your website. Often i prefer to use owl Carousel. Include the jquery and css files into you setup.

You can download it from here [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/)

Now Goto app/design/frontend/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml

Implement your carousel over here. If you are using owl carousel you can use the below code  for it:

```
<?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
<div class="more-views">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('More Views') ?></h2>
    <ul id="prod-thumb" class="product-image-thumbs owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
        <?php
        if (($filterClass = $this->getGalleryFilterHelper()) && ($filterMethod = $this->getGalleryFilterMethod()) && !Mage::helper($filterClass)->$filterMethod($_product, $_image)):
            continue;
        endif;
        ?>
        <li class="item">
            <a class="thumb-link" href="#" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" data-image-index="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(75); ?>"
                     width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after'); ?>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery("#prod-thumb").owlCarousel({
    items : 6,
    itemsCustom : [
        [320, 3],
        [480, 4],
        [600, 5],
        [760, 4],
        [800, 4],
        [1024, 6],
        [1400, 6],
        [1600, 6]
      ],    
    lazyLoad : true,
    navigation : true,
    pagination: false
  }); 

});
</script>
```

You can check for owl tutorial on its website

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with Dexters code. Replacing the entire 'more-views' block with the code provided, will result in the whole block disappearing as owl-carousel will add 'display: none;' and the js function to re-add 'display: block;' will not take effect.
Strangely, if I remove the class "gallery-image" from the "image-main" img, the carousel will work. However, opening a thumb from the carousel will not load it in the product-image div.